# Ubuntu HTTP latency falling into strange quantiles

Tags: linux, ubuntu, performance, performance-tuning, conntrack

I have an Ubuntu 10.10 server with plenty of RAM, bandwidth and CPU. I'm seeing a strange, repeatable pattern in the distribution of latencies when serving static files from both Apache and nginx. Because the problem is common to both http servers, I'm wondering if I have misconfigured or poorly tuned Ubuntu's networking or cache parameters.

`ab -n 1000 -c 4 http://apache-host/static-file.jpg`:

```
Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      5
  66%   3007
  75%   3009
  80%   3011
  90%   9021
  95%   9032
  98%  21068
  99%  45105
 100%  45105 (longest request)
```

`ab -n 1000 -c 4 http://nginx-host/static-file.jpg`:

```
Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     19
  66%     19
  75%   3011
  80%   3017
  90%   9021
  95%  12026
  98%  12028
  99%  18063
 100%  18063 (longest request)
```

The results consistently follow this kind of pattern - 50% or more of requests served as expected, then the remainder falling into discrete bands, with the slowest a few orders of magnitude slower.

Apache is 2.x and has mod_php installed. nginx is 1.0.x and has Passenger installed (but neither app server should be in the critical path for a static file). Load average was around 1 when each test was run (server has 12 physical cores). 5GB free ram, 7GB cached swap. Tests were run from localhost.

Here are the configuration changes I have made from Ubuntu server 10.10 defaults:

```
/etc/sysctl.conf:
    net.core.rmem_default = 65536
    net.core.wmem_default = 65536
    net.core.rmem_max = 16777216
    net.core.wmem_max = 16777216
    net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 16777216
    net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 65536 16777216
    net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 16777216 16777216 16777216
    net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 1
    net.ipv4.route.flush = 1
    net.ipv4.tcp_no_metrics_save = 1
    net.ipv4.tcp_moderate_rcvbuf = 1
    net.core.somaxconn = 8192 

/etc/security/limits.conf:
    * hard nofile 65535
    * soft nofile 65535
    root hard nofile 65535
    root soft nofile 65535

other config:
    ifconfig eth0 txqueuelen 1000
```

Please let me know if this kind of problem rings any bells, or if more information about the config would be helpful. Thanks for your time.

**Update:** Here's what I'm seeing after increasing `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max` as suggested below:

```
Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      2
  66%      2
  75%      2
  80%      2
  90%      3
  95%      3
  98%      3
  99%      3
 100%      5 (longest request)
```

Comment: You check the error logs on both apache and nginx as well as `dmesg`?

Comment: Also, consider that you are maybe hitting a limit with `ab` side of things....

Comment: Also also, when you say localhost are you hitting `http://localhost` ? Could there be a DNS bottleneck? How big is this static file? Even your 50% doesn't add up to me, should be 0-1MS for localhost

Comment: Wow. `dmesg` told the tale: `nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet.` Did `sudo sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max=131072` and the problem is gone: 100% of requests in 6ms. Thank you, @KyleBrandt!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Going off your comment that it was the `nf_conntrack` full problem, you can either increase the conntrak table:

`sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max=131072`

Or if you are already behind a firewall you can just exempt HTTP traffic from connection tracking:

```
# iptables -L -t raw
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
NOTRACK    tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:www 
NOTRACK    tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:www 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
NOTRACK    tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:www 
NOTRACK    tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:www
```

Comment: @EliotShepard: One other thing when benchmarking is to watch how many sockets are sitting open with `netstat`. You were probably starting a new test before old ones cleared up. If you use a load balancer, you will pay 2x in terms of connections as well. You might want to looking into some `proc` socket recycle / reuse options as well if you have a lot of traffic in production.